# Is it possible to scale a HTML DIV with all its contents?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

For example if it has animated elements inside and you want to scale it to fit the browser window, is it possible? Or do you have to modify every single child element separately?

Comment: There's a css transform scale that would probably do that, haven't tried it as it sounds like a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

Images scale well if there big enuff to start with, you need to use percentages tho, 4 fonts you need to use css media queries to scale them as the div scales.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the entire element and all contents proportionally using the CSS `transform` property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), the following would make your element 200% larger than normal:

```
#my_element {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

You will need the appropriate browser prefix if you want backwards compatibility (`-webkit-`, `-ms-`, etc).